# reflect first input value to second input field conditionally (based on checkbox)

Tags: jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

First input field

```
<input type="text" id="prmnt_a1" ng-model="prmnt_a1" class="customInput" placeholder="Address Line 1"/>
```

checkbox

```
<input type="checkbox" id="same" ng-model="same" ng-change="stateChanged(same)"/>
```

second input

```
 <input type="text" id="prmnt_a2" ng-model="prmnt_a2" class="customInput" placeholder="Address Line 2"/>
```

if checkbox is true then first input value should reflecting to second input field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do it purely from the view then you can use `ng-change`:

```
<input type="text" id="prmnt_a1" ng-model="prmnt_a1" class="customInput" placeholder="Address Line 1"/>

<input type="checkbox" id="same" ng-model="same" ng-change="stateChanged(same); same ? prmnt_a2 = prmnt_a1 : false"/>

<input type="text" id="prmnt_a2" ng-model="prmnt_a2" class="customInput" placeholder="Address Line 2"/>
```

Note that this will only set the value of the second input once (when the checkbox is checked), if the user goes back to the first input and changes it again the second input won't update, if you want the second input to update in that case as well then you will have to add an `ng-change` to the first input too:

```
<input ng-change="same ? prmnt_a2 = prmnt_a1 : false" type="text" id="prmnt_a1" ng-model="prmnt_a1" class="customInput" placeholder="Address Line 1"/>
```

Comment: i will try that but in case if i want to run another method on same element then what will be the order of function execution.

Comment: @sumitchoudhary don't understand what you mean exactly. Do you mean if you want to run another method inside the `ng-change` as well? if that's the case then you can run multiple methods/functions as long as you seperate them with `;`. Just like i did here: `ng-change="stateChanged(same); same ? prmnt_a2 = prmnt_a1 : false"`

Answer (score 3):

Try this angular code

```
$scope.stateChanged = function(same){
    if(same == true){
        $scope.prmnt_a2 = $scope.prmnt_a1;
    }else {
        $scope.prmnt_a2 = '';
    }
}
```

Comment: i have tried this but again i have to set all fields. but want a shortest way like ng-attr-value={{prmnt_a1}}

Answer (score 1):

Try this :Register a change event handler for checkbox and set / uset input values

```
$(function(){
  $('#same').change(function(){
    //set input value for checkbox true
    if($(this).is(':checked'))
   {
     $('#prmnt_a2').val($('#prmnt_a1').val());
   }
   else
   {
    //clear input box value
    $('#prmnt_a2').val('');
   }
  });
});
```

Comment: i agree with your approach but i don't want to write too much code. i think there is a batter way to do this in Angular.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure but here is soe things you can try :

```
ng-change="prmnt_a2 = (same)?prmnt_a1:''"
```

Here is a tricky but full HTML way that should work :

```
<div ng-if="same==false">
    <input type="text" id="prmnt_a2" ng-model="prmnt_a2" class="customInput"      placeholder="Address Line 2"/>
</div>
<div ng-if="same==true">
    <input type="text" id="prmnt_a2" ng-init="prmnt_a2=prmnt_a1" disabled ng-model="prmnt_a2" class="customInput" placeholder="Address Line 2"/>
</div>
```

Note : ng-init is not made to be used like this usually and be sure to use ng-if and not ng-show/hide.

Otherwise if this doesn't work : custom directive or a function/$watch in the controller. ng-attr just won't work here.

EDIT : for a custom directive this is what would look like the code :

```
.directive('myDirective', function(){
   return{
      restrict : 'A',
      scope:{
         same:'=myBoolean'
         value:'=myValue'
      },
      require:'ngModel',
      link:function(scope, element, attr, ngModelCtrl){
          scope.$watch('same', function(newValue){
             if(newValue){
                ngModel.setViewValue(scope.value);          
             }
          });
      }
   }
}

<input type="text" id="prmnt_a2" ng-init="prmnt_a2=prmnt_a1" ng-disabled="same" ng-model="prmnt_a2" my-directive my-boolean="same" my-value="prmnt_a1" class="customInput" placeholder="Address Line 2"/>
```

This directive is fairly basic. If you need more complex stuff, check documentation on the net.

Comment: but in this approach again i have to write the extra code for each element

Comment: I just added a sample of what will it look like with a custom directive, check it.